# mysql right data type for gender and secretquestion

Tags: mysql

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'enum('m''f'), `secretquestion` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `answer` varch' at line 6

```
create table user_login (
     `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
     `emailid` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
     `password` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
     `retypepassword` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
     `gender` char(1) enum('m''f'),
     `secretquestion` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     `answer` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
     `mobileno` char(10)NOT NULL,
     `dob`DATE NOT NULL,
     `occupation` varchar(30)NOT NULL,                          
     `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
     `state` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
     `pincode` char(6) NOT NULL,
     `checkbox` tinyint(1));
```

Comment: I’m not sure where you’re located, but my mobile number is longer than 10 characters.

Answer (score 7):

use

```
gender char(1) enum('m','f'),
```

Comment: I would suggest not to limit the gender to 'm'/'f' only. Make it an open enumeration. Check with the target's audience (client's) jurisdiction for more information. Here is an [example from Germany](http://www.lifesitenews.com/news/generation-x-germany-to-allow-third-blank-gender-for-birth-certificates). AFAIK there might be as many as 5 values in some cases, including an explicit no-value `will not say/specify` – compare to "unknown" NULL or explicit `undetermined`.

Answer (score 4):

An ENUM is a string object with a value chosen from a list of permitted values that are enumerated explicitly in the column specification at table creation time.
use `gender char(1) enum('m','f')`

```
create table user_login (
         `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
         `emailid` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
         `password` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
         `retypepassword` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
         `gender` char(1) enum('m','f'),
         `secretquestion` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
         `answer` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
         `mobileno` char(10)NOT NULL,
         `dob`DATE NOT NULL,
         `occupation` varchar(30)NOT NULL,                          
         `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
         `state` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
         `pincode` char(6) NOT NULL,
         `checkbox` tinyint(1));
```

Comment: I got this error from mysql 8.x  <charset clause>, <column generated clause>, <constraint>, AUTO_INCREMENT, BINARY, BYTE, COLLATE, COLUMN_FORMAT, COMMENT, DEFAULT, ON, SRID, STORAGE or UNICODE expected, got 'enum

Answer (score 3):

```
"CREATE TABLE tbl_users (    
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,     
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,    
lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,    
email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,    
password VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,    
mobile_no CHAR(20) NOT NULL,    
###gender ENUM('m','f') NOT NULL,###    
country VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,    
state VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,    
city VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,    
pin CHAR(10),    
address VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,    
reg_date TIMESTAMP    
)";
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use a `CHAR` datatype with an `ENUM` datatype because they are both a string datatype, it's like you're using a `CHAR` string datatype with a `VARCHAR` or `TEXT` which is not **true**.

You can use

```
Gender ENUM('M', 'F'),
```